# HTML Email Template shows HTML tags - Mimetype declared

Tags: html, css, email

I have an HTML Email template that sends text that uses HTML tags (
 or <a href... for example).
However, when the email is actually sent, the tags are shown. So instead of:

```
This is a 
Test
```

I'm getting this:

```
This is a<br>Test
```

On the actual email.
I know this has been asked around, but I haven't been able to find the error / missing piece on my template.
Can anyone help please? This is my head piece:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" style="padding:0;Margin:0">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
<meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">
<!--  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">  -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
<meta content="telephone=no" name="format-detection">
<title>New message 2</title><!--[if (mso 16)]>
    <style type="text/css">
    a {text-decoration: none;}
    </style>
    <![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><style>sup { font-size: 100% !important; }</style><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]>
<xml>
    <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
    <o:AllowPNG></o:AllowPNG>
    <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
    </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
</xml>
<![endif]-->
<style type="text/css">
#outlook a {
    padding:0;
}
.ExternalClass {
    width:100%;
}
.ExternalClass,
.ExternalClass p,
.ExternalClass span,
.ExternalClass font,
.ExternalClass td,
.ExternalClass div {
    line-height:100%;
}
.es-button {
    mso-style-priority:100!important;
    text-decoration:none!important;
}
a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
    color:inherit!important;
    text-decoration:none!important;
    font-size:inherit!important;
    font-family:inherit!important;
    font-weight:inherit!important;
    line-height:inherit!important;
}
.es-desk-hidden {
    display:none;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:0;
    max-height:0;
    line-height:0;
    mso-hide:all;
}
.es-button-border:hover a.es-button, .es-button-border:hover button.es-button {
    background:#ffffff!important;
}
.es-button-border:hover {
    background:#ffffff!important;
    border-style:solid solid solid solid!important;
    border-color:#3d5ca3 #3d5ca3 #3d5ca3 #3d5ca3!important;
}
@media only screen and (max-width:600px) {p, ul li, ol li, a { line-height:150%!important } h1, h2, h3, h1 a, h2 a, h3 a { line-height:120%!important } h1 { font-size:20px!important; text-align:center } h2 { font-size:16px!important; text-align:left } h3 { font-size:20px!important; text-align:center } .es-header-body h1 a, .es-content-body h1 a, .es-footer-body h1 a { font-size:20px!important } h2 a { text-align:left } .es-header-body h2 a, .es-content-body h2 a, .es-footer-body h2 a { font-size:16px!important } .es-header-body h3 a, .es-content-body h3 a, .es-footer-body h3 a { font-size:20px!important } .es-menu td a { font-size:14px!important } .es-header-body p, .es-header-body ul li, .es-header-body ol li, .es-header-body a { font-size:10px!important } .es-content-body p, .es-content-body ul li, .es-content-body ol li, .es-content-body a { font-size:16px!important } .es-footer-body p, .es-footer-body ul li, .es-footer-body ol li, .es-footer-body a { font-size:12px!important } .es-infoblock p, .es-infoblock ul li, .es-infoblock ol li, .es-infoblock a { font-size:12px!important } *[class="gmail-fix"] { display:none!important } .es-m-txt-c, .es-m-txt-c h1, .es-m-txt-c h2, .es-m-txt-c h3 { text-align:center!important } .es-m-txt-r, .es-m-txt-r h1, .es-m-txt-r h2, .es-m-txt-r h3 { text-align:right!important } .es-m-txt-l, .es-m-txt-l h1, .es-m-txt-l h2, .es-m-txt-l h3 { text-align:left!important } .es-m-txt-r img, .es-m-txt-c img, .es-m-txt-l img { display:inline!important } .es-button-border { display:block!important } a.es-button, button.es-button { font-size:14px!important; display:block!important; border-left-width:0px!important; border-right-width:0px!important } .es-btn-fw { border-width:10px 0px!important; text-align:center!important } .es-adaptive table, .es-btn-fw, .es-btn-fw-brdr, .es-left, .es-right { width:100%!important } .es-content table, .es-header table, .es-footer table, .es-content, .es-footer, .es-header { width:100%!important; max-width:600px!important } .es-adapt-td { display:block!important; width:100%!important } .adapt-img { width:100%!important; height:auto!important } .es-m-p0 { padding:0px!important } .es-m-p0r { padding-right:0px!important } .es-m-p0l { padding-left:0px!important } .es-m-p0t { padding-top:0px!important } .es-m-p0b { padding-bottom:0!important } .es-m-p20b { padding-bottom:20px!important } .es-mobile-hidden, .es-hidden { display:none!important } tr.es-desk-hidden, td.es-desk-hidden, table.es-desk-hidden { width:auto!important; overflow:visible!important; float:none!important; max-height:inherit!important; line-height:inherit!important } tr.es-desk-hidden { display:table-row!important } table.es-desk-hidden { display:table!important } td.es-desk-menu-hidden { display:table-cell!important } .es-menu td { width:1%!important } table.es-table-not-adapt, .esd-block-html table { width:auto!important } table.es-social { display:inline-block!important } table.es-social td { display:inline-block!important } .es-desk-hidden { display:table-row!important; width:auto!important; overflow:visible!important; max-height:inherit!important } }
</style>
</head>
```

Thanks

Edit: adding HTML Template body

```
<table width="95%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td background="#IMAGE#" bgcolor="#ddf3e9" width="50" height="130" valign="top" class="bgresize" style="background-size: 550px 130px;; object-fit: fill;">

<!--[if gte mso 9]>
<v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:700px;height:150px;">
<v:fill type="frame" src="#IMAGE#" color="#ffffff" />
<v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
<![endif]-->

        <div>
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td width="30" align="left" valign="top" style="font-size: 0%;" class="mobile-hidden"><img src="Spacer.gif" width="30" height="1" style="display: block;" border="0"/></td>
                <td align="left" valign="top" class="mobile-padding"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                        <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding-top: 65px;" class="padding65"><span class="banner-heading55" style="#TITLE_COLOR#font-family: Georgia, serif; font-size: 30px;">#IMAGE_TEXT#</span></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    </table></td>
                <td width="30" align="left" valign="top" class="mobile-hidden" style="font-size: 0%;"><img src="Spacer.gif" width="30" height="1" style="display: block;" border="0"/></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
</v:textbox>
</v:rect>
<![endif]-->

    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>



<body style="width:100%;font-family:helvetica, 'helvetica neue', arial, verdana, sans-serif;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;padding:0;Margin:0">
    <div class="es-wrapper-color" style="background-color:#ffffff"><!--[if gte mso 9]>
            <v:background xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="t">
                <v:fill type="tile" color="#ffffff"></v:fill>
            </v:background>
        <![endif]-->
    <table class="es-wrapper" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;padding:0;Margin:0;width:100%;height:100%;background-repeat:repeat;background-position:center top;background-color:#ffffff">
        <tr>
            <td style="Margin:0">
            <p style="padding-bottom: 10px; Margin:0;line-height:25px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;font-size:20px;color:#292928"><b>#GREETING#</b></p>
            <div style="padding-bottom: 35px; line-height: 1.4; Margin:0;line-height:25px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;font-size:18px;color:#292928">#GREETING_BODY#</div>
            <br><br>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td style="Margin:0">
            <p style="padding-bottom: 10px; Margin:0;line-height:25px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;font-size:20px;color:#292928"><b>#SECTION1_TITLE#</b></p>
            <div style="padding-bottom: 20px; line-height: 1.4; Margin:0;line-height:25px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;font-size:18px;color:#292928">#SECTION1_BODY#</div>
            <br>
        </tr>
        
        
        <tr>
            <td style="Margin:0">
            <p style="padding-bottom: 10px; Margin:0;line-height:25px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;font-size:20px;color:#292928"><b>#SECTION4_TITLE#</b></p>
            <div style="padding-bottom: 20px; line-height: 1.4; Margin:0;line-height:25px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;font-size:18px;color:#292928">#SECTION4_BODY#</div>
            <br>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td style="Margin:0">
            <p style="padding-bottom: 10px; Margin:0;line-height:25px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;font-size:20px;color:#292928"><b>#SECTION5_TITLE#</b></p>
            <div style="padding-bottom: 20px; line-height: 1.4; Margin:0;line-height:25px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;font-size:18px;color:#292928">#SECTION5_BODY#</div>
            <br>
        </tr>
        
    </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you provide any additional information on how you are sending the template or provide the whole template? Also instead of <br> tag you could try '&lt;br&gt;'. This can help ensure compatibility with more email clients.

Comment: Thank you @TheLittleCousin just added my full template.
Used '&lt;br&gt;' as suggested but instead of a break it showed  '&lt;br&gt;' as text.
Do you know what might be happening perhaps? Thanks!

Comment: @JB999 `&lt;br&gt;` is HTML encoded tag, so it will never be treated as actual tag. Always use `<>` for tags, not their escaped representations

Comment: Also note, that you have invalid HTML structure: `<td><tbody>` is not good as each table `tbody` must be direct child of `table`. In addition, you do not close your `<td>`s. Try using HTML validator first

Comment: What kind of email client you are using? Maybe adding `/` to the tag helps? `<br/>` instead of `<br>`

Comment: Thank you @Justinas I'm using Outlook desktop and Outlook.com (thankfully, the email doesn't need to be send to other clients). Tried using / but got the same result.
Will update the structure, do you think that might have something  to do with it? Or maybe the Divs I have? (have them mostly due to a variable image I need to render). Thanks!

Comment: @JB999 So a) Ensure your HTML is valid. b) Output your HTML directly to browser and see if error persist. If so - fix it. If not - client specific issue: try other clients or try looking for client bug reports

Comment: Forgot to mention, issue is only for replaced Text. So for example, when replacing my variable #IMAGE_TEXT# with say 'this is a <br> title'. That's where I would get the error.